# Padrão para tipificar erros/exceções?

Tags: javascript, exceção, tipagem

Até onde sei, JavaScript não tem tipificação de erro.

Em C# e Java, e possível fazer coisas do tipo:

```
try {
    /* .. snip .. */
} catch (FooException foo) {
    /* .. snip .. */
} catch (BarException bar) {
    /* .. snip .. */
} catch (NotEnoughCoffeException nec) {
    /* .. snip .. */
} /* etc. */
```

E assim damos um tratamento de erro diferente para cada tipo de exceção.

Em javascript, o melhor que temos é:

```
try {
    /* .. snip .. */
} catch (couldBeAnything) {
    /* dize-me com quem erras e te direi quem és */
}
```

E o que é pior, não tem nem [tipagem de pato](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)  que ajude nessa hora.

Quando temos algum código em JavaScript que pode falhar de várias formas diferentes... Existe algum padrão de design, alguma metodologia para identificar o que ocorreu? Alguma forma de inserir um código de erro na exceção, por exemplo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem as exceções condicionais (semelhante ao que terá em C# 6) que é até mais flexível que isso, você pode filtrar qualquer coisa:

```
try {
    myroutine(); // pode lançar umas das três exceções abaixo
} catch (e if e instanceof TypeError) {
    // código que manipula a exceção TypeError
} catch (e if e instanceof RangeError) {
    // código que manipula a exceção RangeError
} catch (e if e instanceof EvalError) {
    // código que manipula a exceção EvalError
} catch (e) {
    // código que manipula exceções não especificadas
    logMyErrors(e); // passa o obejto da exceção para um manipular
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/TypeException.js)

Neste caso específico a verificação (a condição), que é basicamente um `if` normal, é em cima do tipo da exceção através do `instanceof`. Então você captura a exceção apenas se ela for uma instância daquele tipo especificado no `if` de cada `catch`.

Não é um recurso padrão e não está disponível em todas as implementações do EcmaScript, então use por conta e risco. E o risco é grande. Não é algo recomendado.

Você pode obter resultado **semelhante** de forma padrão:

```
try {
    myroutine(); // pode lançar umas das três exceções abaixo
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
       // código que manipula a exceção TypeError
    } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
       // código que manipula a exceção RangeError
    } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
       // código que manipula a exceção EvalError
    } else {
       // código que manipula exceções não especificadas
       logMyErrors(e); // passa o obejto da exceção para um manipular
    }
}
```

Fonte: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Answer (score 1):

Para o tratamento de erros e exceções como você exemplificou muito bem em sua pergunta, pode ser visto nesse link: [Tratamento de exceções](http://templecoding.com/blog/2012/12/14/tratamento-de-excecoes-em-javascript/) aonde expõe os tipos de erros e de construtores de objetos de erro.

Em minhas pesquisas puder encontrar também referencias com relação a tratamento de exceções para a windows store que pode ser visualizado nesse link :[Tratamento global de exceções](http://caioproiete.net/pt/tratamento-global-de-excepcoes-aplicacoes-javascript-para-windows-store-apps/)